# Does [NSXMLParser initwithcontentsofurl:...] lock while loading?

Tags: objective-c, nsxmlparser

I'm loading a rather simple XML file from a URL. I wanted to show the network activity indicator while the parser is loading the file, but obviously not while it is parsing.

Question: Does the initWithContentsOfUrl: method lock program execution while the document is loaded from the url? In other words, is the code below correct?

It seems obvious to me that this is okay, but I wanted to make 100% sure.

```
NSString* const urlString = @"...";
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
NSXMLParser* parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This article explains it pretty well http://akosma.com/2010/05/28/initwithcontentsofurl-methods-considered-harmful/:

> The main problem with these methods, of course, is the fact that they
>   are **synchronous**; this means that the thread executing them (usually
>   the UI thread) **will block completely until they return**, and in most
>   applications this means that you are de-facto blocking the whole
>   application for an unknown amount of time. This means that no buttons
>   or UI widgets will react to input, no navigation will be possible, no
>   touch events will be delivered or executed, nothing will happen at all
>   until the network operation completes.
>
> Even worse; when using initWithContentsOfURL:, there is no timeout,
>   there is no meaningful feedback for network failures, and no way for
>   the user to cancel the current network operation. This last factor
>   justifies by itself not using initWithContentsOfURL: at all; you must
>   never ship code that leads to a bad user experience. Your users will
>   resent this and will complain!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display download progress, you will need to download the file yourself using something like `NSURLConnection`, then pass the local file path to the XML parser.

Comment: No, not interested in the progress percentage. Just need to know when it's finished, and the question basically comes down to wether initWithContentsOfUrl works with a synchronous or asynchronous NSURLConnection. Meaning if it is indeed synchronous, I can (probably) safely assume the download is done after initWithContentsOfURL returns.

Comment: Even if you can assume it's done, your GUI update – `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES]` – won't be visible because the synchronous method is preventing the GUI from redrawing. The GUI doesn't get redrawn until you return to the event loop.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does block. So your activity indocator won't be displayed.