# Slow default access crash in iOS

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

I have been programming for 3 years on iOS, heavily using core data. However, I have never come across a crash like this before and have no idea why this is occurring. This current app is only 4 very simple view controllers, saving to nsdefaults only about 5 different times. The error I am confused on is "Slow defaults access for key ClientState took 0.037632 seconds, tolerance is 0.020000". I have noted where in my code it says the problem is in my code. Also, this is long after the view controller has loaded. This process occurs after a button press. Lastly, this crash only happens half the time, meaning there are occasions when the code actually works without a crash.

```
 NSUserDefaults *ab = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSString *frcrat = [ab objectForKey:@"frcrat"];

        NSString *lapper = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text;

        spinner.hidden = NO;
        [spinner startAnimating];
        delem = NULL;
        delem = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; //Line after this line gives error Thread 1: Exc_bad_access (code = 1, address=0xe0bb2f85)
        NSString *urlString = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.mywebsite.com/enum.php?fracat=%@&num=%@&sap=%@", frcrat, lapper, _sna]stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding : NSUTF8StringEncoding ];
        NSXMLParser *Parser = [[[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]] autorelease];
        [Parser setDelegate:self];
        [Parser parse];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not even related to nsuser defaults. It was because of the string _sna. I instead saved that string in nsuserdefaults and reloaded it when I needed it as NSString *snameri. Thanks apple debugger for giving me an inappropriate error.

Answer (score 1):

I assume this code is placed somewhere in your view controller initialization.

The warning you're getting means that it's taking too long for the view controller to load, and this is clearly due to the `initWithContentsOfURL:` call in your code.

As you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961270/does-nsxmlparser-initwithcontentsofurl-lock-while-loading), `initWithContentsOfURL:` is **blocking**, meaning that you should never call it on the main thread. You should perform the XML parser initialization asynchronously. Something like:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    NSString *urlString = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.mywebsite.com/enum.php?fracat=%@&num=%@&sap=%@", frcrat, lapper, _sna]stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding : NSUTF8StringEncoding ];
    NSXMLParser *parser = [[[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]] autorelease];
    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser parse];
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Although this is not during my view controller initialization (it occurs after submitting from an alert view), I will look into your iniWithContentsOfURL blocking method suggestion.

Comment: It still gave the slow default error. Sorry, but thanks for trying.